# Time after time’s lyrics are difficult

Tags: lyrics

> Flashback, warm nights almost left behind
>   Suitcase of memories, time after—
>   Sometimes you picture me

I wonder what the subject noun of the sentence is.
Is “time after” the abbreviation of “time after time”?

Comment: JamesK's answer is absolutely correct. Do not expect to find grammar learning resources in song lyrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are lyrics and not prose. The rules for grammatical prose are not being used.

> ### **Warning**
>
> Lyrics are good for developing pronunciation and developing vocabulary (and can be fun to learn) but they are no good for grammar.

You have a series of sentence fragments: "Flashback",  "warm nights", "Suitcase of memories", and so on. These are not sentences and have no verb, and so have no subject. They seem to be intended to be evocative rather than meaningful. They evoke ideas of "remembering good times in the past"

At the end there is a sentence: "Sometimes you picture me". Here "you" is the subject (picture is the verb, me is the object, sometimes is an adverb)

Comment: The word 'time' which may seems to be required is omitted so that the lyrics fit the tune.